# Why does the sorted dataframe rearrange when plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, alphanumeric

Originally the dataframe, df, was sorted I'm assuming as a string but was able to sort the alphanumeric vector:

```
df <- df[mixedorder(as.character(df$ID)),]
```

When creating a barplot the (x-axis) order changes back to `1 10a 10b 11` even though I explicitly changed the order to `1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: In characters 1 then 10 then 11. Because it is not numeric. If you just assign a numeric value to each the use the `reorder()` function on your x value in the first `aes()`. Example `x = reorder(ID,numericID)` then it will order the way you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID=(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10a", "10b", "11")), 
                 y=c(seq(100,500,100), 150, 155, 180), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

### Simple Fix for Simple Data

```
df$numId<-1:nrow(df)

ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(ID,numId), y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x='ID', y='Value')
```

Result

[image]

### Create a function to make numberic value

```
create_id<-function(x) {
  if(!grepl('[a-z]',x,ignore.case = TRUE)) {
    return(as.numeric(x))
  } else {
    letter<-tolower(gsub('[0-9]+',"",x))
    letter_value<-which(letters==letter)/100
    number<-as.numeric(gsub('[a-z]',"",x)) + letter_value
    return(number)
  }
}

df<-df %>%
  group_by(ID, y) %>%
  mutate(nid = round(create_id(ID),3))

ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(ID,nid), y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x='ID', y='Value')
```

Result

[image]

Thank you to @user12728748 for the answer as well as providing the dataframe code. My answer is only here to satisfy the ggplot2 tag in the question. The answer above is just as suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be dealing with factors, or a character vector that gets coerced into an alphabetically sorted factor when graphing, so you turn it into a factor if it is not already a factor, and reorder the factor levels, not sort the data.frame by the ID:

```r
df <- data.frame(a=factor(as.character(c(1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22))))
df <- data.frame(ID=factor(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10a", "10b", "11")), 
                 y=c(seq(100,500,100), 150, 155, 180))
df <- df[order(df$ID), ]
df$ID
#> [1] 1   10a 10b 11  2   3   4   5  
#> Levels: 1 10a 10b 11 2 3 4 5
df <- df[gtools::mixedorder(as.character(df$ID)),]
df$ID
#> [1] 1   2   3   4   5   10a 10b 11 
#> Levels: 1 10a 10b 11 2 3 4 5
barplot(y~ID, data=df)
```

[image]

```r
df$ID <- factor(df$ID, levels=levels(df$ID)[gtools::mixedorder(levels(df$ID))])
barplot(y~ID, data=df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

- edited dealing with the factor re-leveling to address the introduced errors.

Comment: ```levels(df$ID) <- levels(df$ID)[gtools::mixedorder(levels(df$ID))]```

That sorted the ID vector but it completely rearranged the Freq column.

Comment: @Ajaff - You were right, and apologies for the mistakes. I have fixed the code in my edit.